# C++ Pointer Char

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++ and I'm now learning about pointers. I'm trying to understand this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char *text = "hello world";
    int i = 0;
    while (*text) {
        i++;
        text++;
    }
    printf("Char num of <%s> = %d", text, i);
}
```

It outputs:

> `Char num of <> = 11`

But why not this:

> `Char num of <hello world> = 11`

Comment: [OT]: Missing `const` for `const char* text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the value of `text` before printing it out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // text starts pointing at the beginnin of "hello world"
    char *text = "hello world"; // this should be const char*
    int i = 0;
    while (*text) {
        i++;
         // text moves forward one character each time in the loop
        text++;
    }
    // now text is pointing to the end of the "hello world" text so nothing to print
    printf("Char num of <%s> = %d", text, i); 
}
```

The value of a char pointer (like `text`) is the location of the character that it is pointing to. If you increase `text` by one (using `text++`) then it points to the location of the next character.

Not sure why you `#include <iostream>` but use `printf()`. Typically in `C++` code you would do this:

```
std::cout << "Char num of <" << text << "> = " << i << '\n';
```

A working example of what you are trying to do:

```
int main()
{
    const char* text = "hello world"; // should be const char*

    int length = 0;
    for(const char* p = text; *p; ++p)
    {
        ++length;
    }

    std::cout << "Char num of <" << text << "> = " << length << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Omg, Did I change the value of text variable by increase the pointer? I tried this and and I printf first variable, and worked!


char *text = "hello world";
    char *first = text;

Comment: @KaanKölköy Yes the value of a char pointer is the *location* of the  character that it is pointing to, increase `text` and it points to the next character.

Comment: Well, thanks. So, Is there a way to print pointer variable after increase the pointer? I gave value of text to another variable and after that increased the pointer and finally printed that another variable.

Comment: No - typically in c++ you would never ever use char* = "whatever". You would never ever use a `while` for counting characters in a string.

Comment: It seems like you didn't understand what your own `while` loop was doing!!

Comment: @KaanKölköy yes you need to take a copy of the pointer. I will add a working example using a `for()` loop that makes a copy of `text` and increments that instead of incrementing `text`.

Answer (score 3):

As your increase `text` until it points to `'\0'`,
the string printed is empty.

Comment: And making it `const` like you commented would've caught that error straight away.

Comment: @user1320881 No it wouldn't. Nothing wrong with incrementing a pointer to `const char`.

Comment: @user1320881 No, that wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - don't use char-string in c++! Use std::string.

Your while loop continues until it reach zero which is the string termination, so %s is just an empty string. The '<' and '>' is still printed even if the string is empty.

Your text pointer start as the following chars:

```
'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'
```

After the first loop, text points to:

```
'e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'
```

After second loop, text points to:

```
'l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','\0'
```

And so on.

The while-loop continues until text points to '\0' which is just an empty string, i.e. "".

Consequently %s doesn't print anything.

In c++ do:

```
int main() {
   std::string text = "hello world";
   cout << "Char num of <" << text << "> = " << text.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: My teacher used chars to teach us pointers. I don't know why.

Comment: In that case.... tell your teacher that c++ is not c - in any decent company you'll get sacked for using char arrays for string in c++

Comment: And BTW - don't use pointers in c++. In most cases you don't have to. In most cases it is a design error - so reconsider the design instead. If you really, really need pointers you should consider unique_ptr and shared_ptr.

Comment: We didn't use char array for work with strings. We did it to learn pointers. If you can tell a better way, I can tell it to my teacher. Me too said it to teacher, but she wanting to teach us.

Comment: @Kaan It's an entirely antiquated approach to teaching C++ but, unfortunately, extremely commonplace. Just run with it then buy yourself [a modern C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) after the course completes.

Comment: @KaanKölköy - in case of text strings you should always use std::string. The standard library contains all the functions you'll need to operate on the string. Example is size/length but also all kind of search functions. For pointers in general - avoid them. For teaching about pointers a more appropriate case would be a vector holding pointers to instances of a class. Ok for teaching - seldom ok for a real program.

Answer (score 1):

`text` is a pointer to a `char`. So when you increment the pointer you make it to point to the next element. The end of a string in C is delimited by the null character. So you are incrementing the pointer until it points to the null character. After that, when you call `printf` it doesn't print anything because it prints characters until reaches the null character but it is already at the null character.
This could be a quick fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *text = "hello world";
    int i = 0;
    while (*text) {
        i++;
        text++;
    }
    printf("Char num of <%s> = %d", text-i, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the loop pointer `text` points to the terminating zero of the string literal because it is increased in the loop.

Also function `printf` is declared in header `<cstdio>` And string literals in C++ have types of constant arrays (Though in C they have types of non-constant arrays. Nevertheless in the both languages you may not change string literals)

You can rewrite the program either like

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    const char *text = "hello world";
    int i = 0;

    while ( text[i] ) ++i;

    std::printf("Char num of <%s> = %d\n", text, i);
}
```

Or like

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    const char *text = "hello world";
    int i = 0;

    for ( const char *p = text; *p; ++p ) ++i;

    std::printf("Char num of <%s> = %d\n", text, i);
}
```

Also it is better instead of C function printf to use standard C++ stream operators.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char *text = "hello world";
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( const char *p = text; *p; ++p ) ++i;

    std::cout << "Char num of <" << text << "> = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: _"Also it is better instead of C function printf to use standard C++ stream operators."_ Why?